# How do I prove that the Riemann curvature tensor is indeed a tensor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

I know that to prove that something is a tensor I have to show that this thing transforms like a tensor, i.e., like below:

$$ R^{'\alpha}{}_{\gamma\phi\lambda} = \partial_{\beta}x^{\alpha'}\partial_{\sigma'}x^{\gamma}\partial_{\mu'}x^{\phi}\partial_{\nu'}x^{\lambda}R^{\beta}{}_{\gamma\phi\lambda}.$$

But I don't know actually how to start the proof. Do I need to apply this tensor to a vector or something like that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: In a word - differential geometry.

Comment: Maybe, the thing is I am studying this subject in a general relativity course, in physics department, so in my head I should ask here.

Comment: If you define the Riemann tensor in a nice way, the tensorial property is evident. All you then have to do is expand out the definition to confirm that it is equal to the standard definition. I would consult Dirac's book "General Relativity" (available as a PDF online) as it takes an economical approach.

Comment: @user1379857: I've looked though Diracs book - he does a bad job of explaining what tensors are. To be honest he just takes them for granted.

Comment: You could prove $[\nabla_a,\,\nabla_b]V_c=R_{abcd}V^d$.

Comment: I've added the add homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on questions of this type.

Comment: Physics.SE is the proper home for this question based on the form of the question -- a mathematician would prefer to say that tensors are multilinear maps and when you compute $[\nabla_a,\nabla_b](\alpha V^c)$ the "cross terms" on the scalar field $\alpha$ cancel leaving $\alpha [\nabla_a, \nabla_b] V^c$ and proving that this is a multilinear map of a $[1,0]$-tensor to a $[1,2]$ tensor, therefore it must be a $[1,3]$-tensor $R^a_{bcd}$. That one is asking about how it behaves under coordinate transforms indicates one is instead taking the physicist's approach to such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a question in mathematics, but it is also a valid question in gravitation. Mathematicians would probably answer this question in a more formal way such that it could be overcomplicated for a physicist who just would like to, in a sense, demonstrate rather than prove.

You need to start from the definition of Riemann curvature tensor, namely,
$$
R_{\alpha\beta\;\mu}^{\;\;\;\nu} = \partial_\alpha \Gamma_{\beta\;\nu}^{\;\,\mu} - \partial_\beta \Gamma_{\alpha\;\nu}^{\;\,\mu} + 
\Gamma_{\alpha\;\kappa}^{\;\,\mu} \Gamma_{\beta\;\nu}^{\;\,\kappa} 
- \Gamma_{\beta\;\kappa}^{\;\,\mu} \Gamma_{\alpha\;\nu}^{\;\,\kappa}
$$
and then transform the connection $\Gamma$ under a general coordinate transformation. As you might know, the connection is not a tensor and it transforms non-homogeneously. However, the additive parts of the transformed connections would cancel out and make the Riemann curvature transform as tensor

Comment: I tried to prove using the definition of a tensor and how It transforms but it went bad. I just proved that $ [\nabla_{a},\nabla_{ b}] V_{c} = R_{abcd} V^{d}$ but I don't quite understand why does it prove that R is a tensor

Comment: That proof can provide that if you know the left-hand side is a tensor, then you would be sure the right-hand side is tensor too. In order to do that, you need to make sure that the covariant derivative operator $\nabla_a$ is a tensor (which is the reason that we use it). For the other way that I mentioned in my answer, can you show what went wrong? What is the definition that you used?